# Ionic 2 AngularJS 2 TypeScript - Google Plus login - error 400

Tags: angular, google-api, ionic2, google-signin

I'm trying to implement Google login in my mobile application.
I have Facebook login with ionic-native.
For GooglePlus I'm using the same ionic-native, I have configured Google Developers for getting Website application keys. I was getting error 400 uri_mismatch but I fix callback urls in my configuration.
In mobile app after login with Google I'm getting screen to login into my account, then it's returning to application with 400 error with message "the operation couldn't be completed. com.google.HTTPStatus error 400". Now I don't have any idea how to repair it.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { GooglePlus } from 'ionic-native';

/*
  Generated class for the Google provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class GoogleProvider {

  public platform : Platform;
  public p : any;

  constructor(public http: Http, platform: Platform) {
    console.log('Hello Google Provider');
    this.platform = platform;
  }

  login() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
          let env = this;
          // user is previously logged and we have his data
          // we will let him access the app
          GooglePlus.login({
            'scopes': '', // optional, space-separated list of scopes, If not included or empty, defaults to `profile` and `email`.
            'webClientId': 'webClientId.apps.googleusercontent.com', // optional clientId of your Web application from Credentials settings of your project - On Android, this MUST be included to get an idToken. On iOS, it is not required.
            'offline': true
          })
          .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            resolve(data);
          }, function (error){
            console.log(error);
            reject(error);
          });
        } else {
          console.log("Please run me on a device");
          reject('Please run me on a device');
        }
      });
    });
    return this.p;
  }

}
```

Comment: add the relevant code..no one can really help you without the context..

Comment: Yes of course, I paste my code

Comment: "webClientId.apps.googleusercontent.com" i replaced with my generated value from developer console

Comment: you are getting it in android or ios?

Comment: on ios device (iPhone 6s plus with the newest version of system)

Comment: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/39 maybe this thread will help

Comment: did you set id during installation? `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus --save --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=myreversedclientid`

Comment: Yes, I have installed plugin with that key, It's written in config.xml in plugin section. I was using your link but didn't find issue 39, now I'm checking this answer Vasanth19 commented on 25 Aug 2016 from Github

Comment: try to place the web client id in your code : `'webClientId': `instead of dummy one.

Comment: In code on my machine I'm having good webClientId